# Replace sub string with bold version in pregmatch in PHP

Tags: php

Hi i have string like this

```
          Intekhab        How are [[1]]<BR/>          khan        I am fine what about [[2]]<BR/>          Intekhab        I am [[3]] too thanks<BR/>
```

I have one array with element like this

`$a = array("Intekhab","khan");` i want to replace those chrachter in array with its bold html like this

```
          <br>Intekhab</br>        How are [[1]]<BR/>          <br>khan</b>        I am fine what about [[2]]<BR/>          Intekhab        I am [[3]] too thanks<BR/>
```

I have alredy tried with

```
str_replace(array("Intekhab","khan"),array("<b>Intekhab</b>","<b>khan</b>"),$string);
```

but it replacing the content inside the like also. the character intekha ,khan must exists on each line first word

Thanks

Comment: `<br>Intekhab</br>` doesn't make the text bold though

Comment: `str_replace(array("Intekhab","khan"),array("<b>Intekhab</b>","<b>khan</b>"));` is missing a third paramter

Comment: Sorry I have added

Comment: Problem is , the function replacing the  character in whole sting  , Like if i want to replace a,b,c with <b>a</b>,<b>b</b>,<b>c</b>   , but a,b,c should be first character of each line

Comment: You need to find a pattern to replace. In this case, maybe you can use `"     khan     "` for example, with all those spaces.